# Configuration stm32f3discovery, work with (or without) Freertos to short delay (µs)

Tags: time, delay, stm32

I'm a newcomer here. I come to you because for my student project I need to establish a communication between the stm32f3 and the DHT11 sensor.

The communication is very specific and i need good masteries on time.

But I never work on µs and i don't know how to use it

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: I might be helpful if you could include some info about what you have already tried.

Comment: Very specific means unknown for us.

Comment: If you expect that someone is gonna look up the datasheets for both components and write a example application for you, you are probably out of luck. Be specific, show us what you tried, show us what doesn't work and I'm sure you'll get some helpful answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The communication interface DHT11 uses is OneWire, which is standardized interface. These microsecond delays needed for it can be implemented using one of MCU's timers, you will just need to set up its prescaler to divide clocks to 1MHz (for 1us resolution), load the value of delay in us into period register and start the timer up. Then you just wait for timer update event. For the whole OneWire communication you can port one of many libraries available on the web.